# Creating objects with random values and sort them by random rating

Tags: c#

I'm very new to c# and have a project which is suppose to have 30 objects with 5 fields; motive, type, rating and price. The values of the fields are suppose to differ in each object and then suppose to be sorted in a descending order based on rating.

I created a method which had the lists for the values and then gave them a random value based on strings in the list. I then also made a integrer for rating and gave it a random value between 0-10. My problem is I've created a loop to do this 30 times and it works just as I want it to except it doesn't sort them by rating.

I've searched through alot to get a way to implement a solution into my code but I can't find anything that works.

Here is the for loop with the lists

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    List<string> Motiv = new List<string> { "Harry Potter", "Djur", "Världens bästa", "Kärlek" };
    List<string> Typ = new List<string> { "Kaffemugg", "Resemuggar", "Termo", "Ölmugg" };

    Random random = new Random();

    int snittbetyg = random.Next(0, 10);
    int pris = random.Next(100, 499);
    int getRdnMotiv = random.Next(Motiv.Count);
    int getRdnTyp = random.Next(Typ.Count);

    List<Mugg> muggList = new List<Mugg>();
    muggList.Add(new Mugg() { Motiv = Motiv[getRdnMotiv], Typ = Typ[getRdnTyp], Snittbetyg = snittbetyg, Pris = pris });

    List<Mugg> sortByRating = muggList.OrderBy(user => user.Snittbetyg).ToList();
    foreach (Mugg mugg in sortByRating)

        Console.WriteLine($"Mugg {i + 1}: " + "Motiv = " + mugg.Motiv + ", Typ = " + mugg.Typ + ", Snittbetyg = " + mugg.Snittbetyg + ", Pris = " + mugg.Pris);
}
```

Class I have to get and set the values

```cs
class Mugg
{
    public string Motiv { get; set; }
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public int Snittbetyg { get; set; }
    public int Pris { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example output? Looks correct to me.

Comment: Move `Random random = new Random();` and `List<Mugg> muggList = new List<Mugg>();` to OUTSIDE (before) the loop! Move the code that sorts and displays the sorts to AFTER the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have all the right parts, just organized incorrectly.

```
List<string> Motiv = new List<string> { "Harry Potter", "Djur", "Världens bästa", "Kärlek" };
List<string> Typ = new List<string> { "Kaffemugg", "Resemuggar", "Termo", "Ölmugg" };

// Important these are outside the loop
// so they are only created ONCE.
Random random = new Random();
List<Mugg> muggList = new List<Mugg>();

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    int snittbetyg = random.Next(0, 10);
    int pris = random.Next(100, 499);
    int getRdnMotiv = random.Next(Motiv.Count);
    int getRdnTyp = random.Next(Typ.Count);
    muggList.Add(new Mugg() { Motiv = Motiv[getRdnMotiv], Typ = Typ[getRdnTyp], Snittbetyg = snittbetyg, Pris = pris });
}

// Don't sort inside the loop.
// Sort after the entire list has been created.
List<Mugg> sortByRating = muggList.OrderBy(user => user.Snittbetyg).ToList();
int j = 1;
foreach (Mugg mugg in sortByRating)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Mugg {j++}: Motiv = {mugg.Motiv}, Typ = {mugg.Typ}, Snittbetyg = {mugg.Snittbetyg}, Pris = {mugg.Pris}");
}
```